# ebay://, tel: etc not working out of browser

Tags: opera-browser

I'm using Opera as browser. I can remember that in the past, when I googled a restaurant, I could dial the phone number right from the search results.

Now, I see in the title bar `tel:<number>`, but the dialer doesn't open.

In addition, I just noticed that an `ebay://` link does also not open the Ebay app but does nothing.

Any idea what I have configured for achieving this behavior? And even more interesting: how can I restore the original behavior?

Comment: What device? Many manufacturers limit this capability to their own applications only... Samsung and HTC are (used to be) notorious for this.

Comment: @acejavelin Moto G 4 Plus

Comment: Hmmm... I don't have a G4+ available for testing, but on a Moto G5+ with stock Nougat firmware it works fine, I went to website with a tel:<number> and tapped it and opened immediately in the dialer app, but when I typed tel:<number> in the title bar it just did a search (Chrome did the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

When weird stuff starts to happen, I suggest to uninstall Opera, reboot your device, and reinstall Opera.

First, check the version of Opera that you have installed, in case you want to reinstall that version, rather than the latest.  You can alway find the older version on a mirror like apkmirror.com.